# Is it possible to build simple pitch labeling system using GStreamer pipeline?

Tags: gstreamer

I have little experience with GStreamer, but I see it is very powerful tool. I wonder wether it is possible to build simple pitch labeling system using GStreamer pipeline. This system should take audio input with one musical note played at sigle time moment and print information about that note: frequency (e.g. 440 Hz) or name (e.g. A4).

I guess [Spectrum element](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/spectrum/index.html?gi-language=c) can probably be used, but unfortunately I don't know how to build even simplest pipeline with this element:

```
gst-launch-1.0 pulsesrc ! # What should I put here?
```

Can you provide at least the simplest working pipeline with Spectrum element? I would appreciate anything that can be used as a starting point for further research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine you would do something like this:

I don't have streamer setup, so I can't test it, but I would suggest trying:

```
gst-launch-1.0 pulsesrc ! audioconvert ! spectrum ! debugspy ! fakesink
```

But debugspy is just for debugging messages sent to the bus!

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/spectrum/index.html?gi-language=c#spectrum

But to be honest, if you see the sample code on that page, a series of messages are output, which contain information about the magnitudes and phases. I don't know how you will use that information for computing the frequency or name, but imagine that to do so you would be better of writing a program rather than using the command line (gst-launch-1.0 )

```
static gboolean
message_handler (GstBus * bus, GstMessage * message, gpointer data)
{
  if (message->type == GST_MESSAGE_ELEMENT) {
    const GstStructure *s = gst_message_get_structure (message);
    const gchar *name = gst_structure_get_name (s);
    GstClockTime endtime;

    if (strcmp (name, "spectrum") == 0) {
      const GValue *magnitudes;
      const GValue *phases;
      const GValue *mag, *phase;
      gdouble freq;
      guint i;

      if (!gst_structure_get_clock_time (s, "endtime", &endtime))
        endtime = GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE;

      g_print ("New spectrum message, endtime %" GST_TIME_FORMAT "\n",
          GST_TIME_ARGS (endtime));

      magnitudes = gst_structure_get_value (s, "magnitude");
      phases = gst_structure_get_value (s, "phase");

      for (i = 0; i < spect_bands; ++i) {
        freq = (gdouble) ((AUDIOFREQ / 2) * i + AUDIOFREQ / 4) / spect_bands;
        mag = gst_value_list_get_value (magnitudes, i);
        phase = gst_value_list_get_value (phases, i);

        if (mag != NULL && phase != NULL) {
          g_print ("band %d (freq %g): magnitude %f dB phase %f\n", i, freq,
              g_value_get_float (mag), g_value_get_float (phase));
        }
      }
      g_print ("\n");
    }
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

They've implemented a message handler. You could modify this code to do whatever you want for calculations with the magnitude / phase. Or output it to some other program.

Using gst-launch makes sense if you know which plugins to use, but it is unclear to me which plugin can be used to compute the frequency / name from the spectrum ( I don't know much about audio / fft). It seems to be one of the few plugins which has a code sample, rather than an example of how to use gst-launch with it, so I'm guessing again that maybe they intend for you to write your own message handler rather than use plugins for output.